# rename io-circe case class field from JSON, but does not match extended trait

Tags: json, scala

I have the following minimal example to illustrate my conundrum, which is that I am using the IO-Circe JSON library and have a Trait that has one property and a bunch of Case Classes that extend that Trait.  In most instances, this works just fine, however I do have a couple of JSON message schemas that I am decoding that have a field that does not match the name in the trait.  I used the @JsonKey notation to do the renaming, which works fine, but then, as I would expect, I get an error that states that the Case Class must be declared abstract or implement the missing property.

```
sealed trait Something { val ts: Instant }

case class SomethingSpecific extends Something(@JsonKey("ts") timestamp: Instant, someOtherValue: Int)
```

Is there a way to make this work "properly"?  Obviously, a quick and dirty workaround is to simply remove the "ts" property from the Trait, but I would prefer not to do that unless it is absolutely the only way to make this work.  I expect to have to support many more different JSON message schemas that could have the same problem.  All message schemas must have a timestamp field, hence putting that property in the Trait.  I need to standardize the timestamp field across all message types.

Thanks in advance for any help you might provide!

Comment: I really do not understand the question, problem. Your case class has to have the `ts` property, period. That is basic inheritance. I do not understand what do you want to do with that `timestamp` field.

Comment: Ah, you are correct, the case class does need to have the ts property.  The rub is that with IO-Circe doing its magic to parse a JSON string (which has "timestamp" for the field name), IO-Circe gives you the ability to rename any given field using that @JsonKey annotation....So, the case class does, indeed have a "ts" property...but not soon enough, perhaps, so the compiler is throwing an error and saying that the "ts" property is missing.  Does that make more sense?  Or am I still doing a bad job of describing the problem?

Comment: What you want to do is not just `final case class SomethingSpecific(@JsonKey("timestamp") ts: Instant, someOtherValue: Int) extends Something`?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am doing temporarily while trying to figure out a more elegant solution.  So, there is no other way to do this?

Comment: Again, not sure what you mean with more elegant and what exactly is the problem with this solution.

Comment: `JsonKey` overrides the name codec uses by replacing the `String` generated from field name. It isn't generating a new field in a class, so compiler has nothing to find, neither sooner nor later.

Comment: So, is there a way to do it so that a field "timestamp" in the JSON string can be converted to "ts" in the case class?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, the reason I wanted to have the "ts" field consistent and in the trait was for others who come after me to see that field and understand that it should be consistent in any extensions to the library they write....I'm with you, if not for that, the "just leave it out of the trait" approach would be a no-brainer...

Comment: @mabossert _"So, is there a way to do it so that a field "timestamp" in the JSON string can be converted to "ts" in the case class"_ - again, isn't that just `final case class SomethingSpecific(@JsonKey("timestamp") ts: Instant, someOtherValue: Int) extends Something`?

Comment: So, @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I tried it the way you suggested and it worked.  I went back to the documentation and I was looking at the Encoder example, hence my confusion with the the substitution of the "timestamp" field for "ts".  In the Decoder, it worked as expected.